# How to expand a value to place it in the ex command?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line

The goal is to create a mapping that will:

- create a mapping for the user --> `remap` does the trick
- that gets the current expression under the cursor --> `expand('<cexpr>')` will do the trick
- put this into the command line, so the user can adjust as necessary

What I've tried so far:

- `:let exp = expand('<cexpr>')` -> gets the value, for example "my_expr"
- `nnoremap = :Evaluate<Space> expand('<cexpr>')` -> writes that text in there instead of resolving it
- `nnoremap <expr> = 'Evaluate '. expand('<cexpr>') . ' = '` --> changes to visual mode

*should* pre-set the ex command to `:Evaluate my_expr` so the user can adjust the expression before pressing enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just missing a colon before `Evaluate`...

```
nnoremap <expr> = ':Evaluate '. expand('<cexpr>') . ' = '
```

When I try it with the colon I get

```
Evaluate foo =
```

...waiting at the command line.

Without the colon I get Visual mode just like you describe. Remember, this is a Normal mode mapping so it's like you literally enter `E` followed by `v` in Normal mode which places you in Visual mode. Adding the colon makes sure you go to the command line first.

Comment: As I'm a "new contributor" here I take the option to not be Q+A in a comment: Thanks, feels a bit dumb to have that asked - but both the explanation and the solution is now clear!

Comment: You're welcome and don't even worry about that. We all overlook small things from time to time. Welcome to Vi&Vim SE...as a contributor. :)